# How to debug es6 tests with babel-jest and node inspector

Tags: node.js, debugging, testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I have no idea how to generate the source maps to debug jest tests on the node inspector right now I am using this command but is generating transpiled code:

```
node --debug-brk ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand
```